# Range function using

Tags: python

```
a=range(4,-1,-1)
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

in this case range function reverse print why?
So result:4,3,2,1,shortly what does it mean "-1" on range function

Comment: The `range()` function accepts 3 parameters _start_, _stop_, and _step_. This is explained in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range. What is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

> range is actually an immutable sequence type

> class range(start, stop[, step])
>
> The arguments to the range constructor must be integers (either
> built-in int or any object that implements the **index** special
> method). If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the
> start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. If step is zero,
> ValueError is raised.
>
> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the
> formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.
>
> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by
> the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and
> r[i] > stop.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the [documentation of `range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range). The first parameter is that start value, the 2nd parameter is the stop value and the 3rd one is the step size. In your example you're thus going from 4 to 0 in steps of -1.

Here's a [tutorial about `range()`](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/).